# EMV Card reader for iphone

Tags: iphone, ipad, smartcard, emv

I am in desperate need for an EMV Card compatible reader for the iPhone... does anyone have any idea what kind of hardware is out there? I steadily find "iZettle" out there with their reader. but I don't think you can use the reader for any other purpose than theirs? I would need to read out a chip card and maybe you have an idea as well where to start?

Thank you!
Sebastian

Comment: Answered and voted it down as it, obviously, isn't a development question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for ISO 7816 compatability. I found [this](http://www.idtechproducts.com/products/mobile-readers/136.html) one through Google search "contact card reader iphone iso 7816". Note that you aren't there with the hardware, you need to have libraries or support.